# List subdirectories only n level deep

Tags: bash, ls

Festival stores voicepack data in the following example directory structure:

`/usr/share/festival/voices/<language>/<voicepack name>`

What is the simplest one-liner (preferably using `ls`) to print out just the `<voicepack name>`'s, in all the potentially numerous `<language>` subdirectories?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I'm on Fedora, and these voicepacks are in a slightly different location:

```
$ ls /usr/share/festival/lib/voices/*/ -1 | grep -vE "/usr|^$"
kal_diphone
ked_diphone
nitech_us_awb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_bdl_arctic_hts
nitech_us_clb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_jmk_arctic_hts
nitech_us_rms_arctic_hts
nitech_us_slt_arctic_hts
```

You can just modify this like so:

```
$ ls /usr/share/festival/voices/*/ -1 | grep -vE "/usr|^$"
```

#### Using find

Using `ls` in this manor is typically frowned upon because the output of `ls` is difficult to parse. Better to use the `find` command, like so:

```
$ find /usr/share/festival/lib/voices -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 \
    -type d -exec basename {} \;
nitech_us_awb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_bdl_arctic_hts
nitech_us_slt_arctic_hts
nitech_us_jmk_arctic_hts
nitech_us_clb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_rms_arctic_hts
ked_diphone
kal_diphone
```

#### Details of find & basename

This command works by producing a list of full paths to files that are exactly 2 levels deep with respect to this directory:

```
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices
```

This list looks like this:

```
$ find /usr/share/festival/lib/voices -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_awb_arctic_hts
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_bdl_arctic_hts
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_slt_arctic_hts
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_jmk_arctic_hts
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_clb_arctic_hts
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_rms_arctic_hts
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/english/ked_diphone
/usr/share/festival/lib/voices/english/kal_diphon
```

But we want the last part of these directories, the leaf node. So we can make use of `basename` to parse it out:

```
$ basename /usr/share/festival/lib/voices/us/nitech_us_awb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_awb_arctic_hts
```

Putting it all together, we can make the `find` command pass each 2 level deep directory to the `basename` command. The notation `basename {}` is what is doing these basename conversions. Find calls it via it's `-exec` switch.

Answer (score 44):

The easiest is

```
ls -d /usr/share/festival/voices/*/*
```

That is expanded by the shell into all sub directories of `/usr/share/festival/voices/` and then to the contents of each of those sub directories.

If you only want to descend to a specific level as your title suggests, with some implementations of `find` like GNU's and some BSD's:

```
find /usr/share/festival/voices/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3 -type d
```

That will find all directories (`-type d`) that are in a subdirectory of `/usr/share/festival/voices/` because of `mindepth 2` but are not deeper than 3 levels down (`maxdepth 3`). From `man find`:

```
   -maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc‐
          tories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0
           means only apply the tests and  actions  to  the  command  line
          arguments.

   -mindepth levels
          Do  not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a
          non-negative integer).  -mindepth  1  means  process  all  files
          except the command line arguments.
```

Answer (score 9):

The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93326/) works correctly
but is somewhat inefficient because it spawns a new `basename` process for
each subdirectory:

```
find /usr/share/festival/lib/voices -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 \
    -type d -exec basename {} \;
```

When possible, it's preferable to use features built into `find` to avoid the
expense of spawning processes.  `find` has a fairly extensive capability to
modify its printed output using the `-printf` action.  The default `-print`
action prints the entire path, but using `-printf` and a format string it's
possible to select portions of the path for printing.  To extract just the
filename portion of the path without the leading directories (as `basename`
does), the format string is `%f`.  To place a newline after each filename,
include `\n` as follows:

```
$ find /usr/share/festival/lib/voices -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 \
    -type d -printf '%f\n'
nitech_us_awb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_bdl_arctic_hts
nitech_us_slt_arctic_hts
nitech_us_jmk_arctic_hts
nitech_us_clb_arctic_hts
nitech_us_rms_arctic_hts
ked_diphone
kal_diphone
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer Michael. I can see the advantage to the way of doing this in your answer, also, but given the work put into [slm's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453) answer I am at two minds about switching the accepted answer. If @slm sees this, and has no issues with choosing this over his, I will return here to change the accepted answer.

Comment: @slm's answer is well explained and covers the more general pattern of using `find` with arbitrary external commands; it's just less efficient for operations that are built into `find`.  I had considered adding a comment to his answer, but that requires more reputation than I have.  There's no need to change your accepted answer, as the currently accepted answer is correct, well explained, and usable as a pattern for the more general case; I just wanted to point out that for this specific case there is a more efficient method.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR; for those just coming here based on the *title* of this question; to "List subdirectories only n level[s] deep": use

```
find -maxdepth N
```

where `N` is any number.

---

Example:

```bash
# list all files and folders 4 levels deep
find -maxdepth 4
```

---

And if you need to search for a particular file or folder, just pipe it to `grep`. Ex:

```
find -maxdepth 4 | grep -i some_file_name
```

Note that the `-i` above makes the grep search of the file and folder names coming out of the `find` command case 'i'nsensitive.

For additional help with `find`, to make it search only *where* you want and find only *what* you want, see also my other answer here: [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830768/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

For someone using bash looking for something simple just using ls:

```
ls -d $PWD/*
```

When creating an alias (in ~/.bash_aliases or wherever), be sure to use single-quotes:

```
alias ldf='ls -d $PWD/*'
```

Not quoting it will result in the shell trying to execute ls.

Double-quoting it will create the alias with the value of $PWD at the time of the alias.

You could use $(pwd) if you prefer, but I don't see the point of spawning a sub-shell when  bash provides $PWD for you.

Comment: this only lists the directories, you should pass it to `| xargs ls`, probably?

Comment: Alas, this doesn't answer the question (prints all the directories under one path; Question was about printing directory names 2 levels downstream from a base folder, while not folders 1 level downstream from a base folder). Unlike forums, this is a question and answer site. In order to keep the amount of superfluous information to a minimum, only things that directly answer the question usually remain. A separate question of how to list subdirectories of a path would allow this answer, but I trust this less-complicated-than-I-asked question would already be asked and comprehensibly answered.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- /usr/share/festival/voices/*/*(N-/:t)
```

Or the GNU `find` + `sort` equivalent:

```
LC_ALL=C find -L /usr/share/festival/voices -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 \
  -name '.*' -prune -o -type d -printf '%f\0' |
  sort -z |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```